# wordpress output posts in different columns?

Tags: php, wordpress

So if I have a simple loop like this:
How would I go about outputting posts in different columns?
Like odd/even posts going into a left and right column (for styling purposes).

I can write a filter to add the classes to each consecutive post, but then I'd need to overwrite them in css on the single/archive pages.
I figure there's got to be a better way to do it in the html structure.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged); 
?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class('clearfix') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<span><?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?></span>

<?php echo '<em>Written by </em> <br>'; the_author_posts_link(); ?> 

<?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>

<?php comments_popup_link('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comments-link', ''); ?>

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php global $more; $more = 0; ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

<?php the_content('Read on...'); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: for styling you need to use css not in php...

Comment: Uh, I know that?

What I want to do is output the posts sequentially in columns.

First post in column 1, second in column 2, third in column 1 again etc.

Comment: Dude, this column stuff is done by CSS... That is what I said...

Comment: So how would I output posts from a wordpress loop in different containers using css?

Comment: You don't need different containers. So, what's the HTML output of the posts? Some kind of `UL` and `LI` right? Can you post them in the question?

Comment: Do you want something like in [this example](http://jsbin.com/enamiw/1)?

Comment: Yes heera, something like that.